# Mysql dump - How to execute a long query with escaping?

Tags: database, mysql

I'm exporting a roundcube MySQL database using `Mysqldump` but sadly it fails when I use a long query. How can I escape this so it works?

> **mysqldump** -t --skip-add-drop-table roundcube contacts --where="select * from contacts where user_id in (select user_id from users where username like '%mysite.com%')" > roundcube_contacts.sql

Running the above gives me this error, so how do I escape the query properly?

> **mysqldump:** Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ /*!50084 SQL_NO_FCACHE */ * FROM `contacts` WHERE select * from contacts where user_id in (select user_id from users where username like '%mysite.com%')': **You have an error in your SQL syntax;** check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from contacts where user_id in (select user_id from users where usernam' at **line 1 (1064)**

Comment: See MySQL docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mysqldump `--where` option specifies the text to be included in the WHERE clause.

You've got a whole statement there, and that generates a syntax error,

```
... WHERE SELECT ... 
          ^
```

mysqldump is already writing the `SELECT * FROM roundcube.contacts`. The --where option is telling mysqldump to include a WHERE keyword, followed by the text you supply, as part of the statement it generates.

You want something more along the lines of:

--where="user_id in (select user_id from users where username like '%mysite.com%')"

so the generated statement would be...

```
... WHERE user_id in ...
          ^
```

Also, the database name and table name should follow the options...

```
mysqldump -t --skip-add-drop-table --where="1=1" roundcube contacts \
  > roundcube_contacts.sql
```